# Styling INPUT["Text"] vs DIV - Input is slightly Bigger

Tags: html, css, input

I'm trying to style an Input tag and a DIV tag.  The DIV will have to be below the input, and they need to have the same width.  However, no matter what I do - the DIV is one pixel smaller than the INPUT.

This shouldn't be happening, especially if (in this example) the two objects are sharing the same CSS class.  I know how to code CSS.  I just have no idea what could be causing the input box to be just slightly bigger.

I've diddled and fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/r8pty4a8/

EDIT: I cannot simply offset by a pixel. The design is using VW units, which are a "responsive" CSS3 measurement unit.  1VW = 1% of the viewport width.

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative">
    <input type="text" class="MyStyle" />
    <div class="MyStyle">Foo</div>
</div>

.MyStyle
{
    height: 6.09375vw;
    line-height: 6.09375vw;
    font-size: 3.05vw;
    padding-left: 2.013vw;
    width: 80vw;
    border: .4vw solid red;
    border-top-left-radius: .3vw;
    border-top-right-radius: .3vw;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You should specify the `font-family`. Currently they are different.

Comment: The boxes will each use a different font family, actually

Comment: Ok then, carry on. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to account for the default `padding-top`/`padding-bottom` on the `input` element.

In Chrome, the element has a default `padding-top`/`padding-bottom` of `1px`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3t4osqc/) - both elements now have the same height.

```
.MyStyle {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 6.09375vw;
    line-height: 6.09375vw;
    font-size: 3.05vw;
    padding-left: 2.013vw;
    width: 80vw;
    border: .4vw solid red;
    border-top-left-radius: .3vw;
    border-top-right-radius: .3vw;
    clear: both;
}
```

You could also use the shorthand - `padding: 0 0 0 2.013vw`. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/10g4sk83/)

Comment: I didn't specify, but its smaller for both width and height. This would solve height, do you have any ideas for width?

Comment: Just looked at your ypdated example, looks great. Thank you!